# How can I amplify cellphone's vibrator signal to switch my home electricity on or off?

Tags: switches, relay, cellphone

I need to connect my Samsung s1 cellphone to my home's lights when I am away. I realised that I can use my cellphones' vibrator signal when I call my "Home" cellphone number. I know that the mentioned signal is less than 2 volts (I don't know exactly!) and to operate such a method, I need a relay to convert this low voltage into regular home electricity voltage (240V).
I tried to find a proper relay, but all what I find is that 5VDC relay from sparkfun:
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/100

Would you advise me if that would work fine with my requirement or not?
Is there any easiest way to do that?
What is your advice please?

NOTE: I have a slight knowledge in electronics!

Comment: You could use an audio ring detector.

Answer (score 2):

You say you have I would "have a slight knowledge in electronics!

So I recommend *not* using your phone vibrator to activate something like a solenoid to control mains electricity.

I recommend buying something which does the mains control.

Search for "home electricity control". You will find lots of products which can turn mains power on and off.

Search for "home electricity control wifi" and you will find products which can turn power on and off, and which can be contacted remotely via the internet.

Once you have control of the mains, and you still want to use your phone, then look at writing an app on that home phone, which talks locally to the mains-controller. If you have a smart phone, e.g. Android, iPhone, etc. then you should be able to write an app relatively easily (there is probably one available already).

Comment: Or search for "domotics"

Comment: Thank you, I don't need to use my mobile phone, but the method should be used by telecommunication sim card, and the control panel should be small as much as it can be.

Comment: @MRAN - I am saying use your phone to talk to the local power control system. Everything done.